# I am trying to execute Typescript written code which I cloned from GitHub But I'm getting these errors while execution. Please help me out

Tags: electron

**PS C:\Users\USER\Downloads\AMS-main> npm install**

> ams-app@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\USER\Downloads\AMS-main
> electron-builder install-app-deps

• electron-builder  version=22.11.7

• loaded configuration  file=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\AMS-main\electron-builder.yml

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2 (node_modules@next\swc-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2 (node_modules@next\swc-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current:
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu@11.1.2 (node_modules@next\swc-linux-x64-gnu):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 821 packages in 7.665s

97 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Executing what? `npm install` ? this installs packages. Are you having problems installing packages? I see a bunch of warnings but no errors.

Comment: Yes executing npm install

Comment: Whats the actual problem? It looks to me like there are no errors, just warnings. I suggest you run your actual code to see if packages downloaded properly,

Comment: Please format the code in code block. Also the exceptions should be added in that block